# combine the content of two seperate queries into one and update

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Hope I am describing this correctly. I have the following two SQL update queries which individually work correctly. I need to take the field updated in the first and use it in a part of the SQL of the second.

This is the first.

```
UPDATE Products_Joined SET TechSpecs = 'var srating_' 
+ Products_Joined.ProductCode + '="' + CAST(Reviews.AverageRating AS VARCHAR) + '";var rcount_' + Products_Joined.ProductCode + '="' + CAST(Reviews.TotalRatings AS VARCHAR) + '";' 

FROM Products_Joined LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT Reviews.ProductCode, AVG(Reviews.Rate) AS AverageRating, COUNT(Reviews.ReviewID) AS TotalRatings
FROM Reviews
GROUP BY Reviews.ProductCode
) AS Reviews ON Products_Joined.ProductCode = Reviews.ProductCode;
```

And this is the second.

```
DECLARE @OpenTag varchar(100)
SET @OpenTag = '<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">'

UPDATE Products_Joined
SET TechSpecs  = STUFF(CAST(TechSpecs AS VARCHAR(MAX)) ,
                   CHARINDEX(@OpenTag, CAST(TechSpecs AS VARCHAR(MAX)) ,1)  + LEN(@OpenTag),
                        CHARINDEX('</script>',CAST(TechSpecs AS VARCHAR(MAX)) ,1)-(CHARINDEX(@OpenTag, CAST(TechSpecs AS VARCHAR(MAX)) ,1)  + LEN(@OpenTag)), 
                   '*****HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO PUT THE FIELD FROM THE FIRST SQL QUERY*******')
WHERE TechSpecs LIKE '%<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">%</script>'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could utilise SQL Server's [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause (SQL server 2005 onwards) to output the result of the first query into a variable, which you can use in the second query.

Comment: While this is very helpful I am having difficulty understanding how I would incorporate this into the above with my very limited SQL knowledge.

Comment: Would you or someone else kindly provide a working solution. THX